# Is it on topic to ask where to download specific drivers?

Tags: discussion, scope, policy

Or should I be asking at Super User?

Specifically, I have just bought a new Lenovo G70-70 in Germany and came with FreeDos. It also has a driver disk, but only for Windows 8.1.

I want to install Windows 7 and, when I try, the installer asks, in a helpful Microsoft way, for a driver, but doesn't say which one.

No problem, thinks I - I'll just download them all. ***BUT***, I can only find them as `.EXE`s, so I would like to ask where to find them as standard `.INF`s.

Would that be permissible here? It's not really asking for a recommendation …

Comment: About asking for a (download) location of a specific software: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1220/is-asking-for-the-canonical-location-of-source-code-on-topic

Comment: The accepted answer there says that it is of-topic. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Mawg: FYI, I left a comment on the answer asking for clarification of special cases.

Comment: The question above is about "where to download drivers". For the on-topicness of drivers questions, see: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/looking-for-specific-drivers-for-my-hardware-on-topic

Answer (score 4):

<sup>Summing up from the comments, to make clear this is "answered":</sup>

In a similar question ([Is asking for the canonical location of source code on-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1220/185)) we "ruled":

> We aren't your search engine. Amusingly enough, this is why we don't like answers that are purely link only, since links die.

And with this said it is off-topic. Same applies here, even with an addition: "Where to download X (in format Y)" is not the topic of SR. While software recommendations of couse shall point out where to get the recommended piece, that's only part of the game: the primary thing here is *recommending good software that matches specific requirements*.

We neither permit questions like "is X a good match for Y" (with X being a specific software, and Y either a task or another software), so it makes even less sense to permit "where to download X".

Comment: I'd agree in most cases, because there's only one vendor, so it's mainly a search engine issue to find it. However, if there is a case with many driver providers, I should be able to ask for a driver with specific requirements. Examples are a) MIDI drivers where latency or ASIO support matters b) virtual joystick drivers with Ethernet support or a certain number of Joystick buttons. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: @ThomasWeller sounds reasonable at least. Context given, I'd not swing the mod-hammer on such a question at least :) But the context would be required then, to distinguish such a question from "the usual candidates".