# Looking for driver recommendations (satisfying particular requirements) for my hardware: On-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Let's say I am looking for an open source driver for my old Zorg2000 Wi-Fi antenna, and I need the driver to work on Linux and let me use the antenna's non-documented wifoobaration features.

Is it on-topic?

*Note: Different from [this "where to download XYZ" question](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1224/is-it-on-topic-to-ask-where-to-download-specific-drivers).*

Answer (score 4):

Only in the proprietary world is there only one driver per piece of hardware.

Several drivers are often available, and some might fit your needs better than the vendor's official driver. That's why when asking for drivers you must specify your requirements:

- What license do you require? For instance, open source only?
- Do you need it to support the most advanced features of the hardware? (please be very specific)
- How reliable is it required to be? (often a trade-off with the previous bullet). Your gaming PC can afford to sometimes crash, your company's printing server not so much.
- What operating system & version does it need to be compatible with?
- What hardware model(s) does it need to be compatible with?
- What undocumented hardware features does it need to support? (often not available in the official drivers)